# Cannot select correct input device in Davinci Resolve?

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone, video-editor

I am using Davinci Resolve for video editing with voice over (basicly followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=10&v=BUVHBdcQRmk).

As input source there is only "ALSA" shown:

[image]

But I can't record my voice with it. Its just ignoring my microphone completly:

[image]

I only have this one audio input (Scarlett Solo USB):

[image]

The microphone works fine with any other software I tried so far. Do I need to configure some settings in Davinci Resolve to make my microphone work?

I have posted this question also at https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=91055&p=0&e=0&sid=bf1570e0bb877f4cbc3baf75edfc67e1

Comment: Add a screenshot of `alsamixer` F5

Answer (score 1):

With the newest update 17.4. and Ubuntu 21.04 it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1179300)

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2021, it is not working. There is a [discussion](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=126287) on the official forum. BlackMagic Design staff acknowledged that problem exists. But still not any update on information when it will be fixed.